# Script only returns the id of first value fetched from database in php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

```
<?php 

    include "connection.php";
    $query="select n_id,title,news from news ";
    $queryr=$con->query($query);
    while($row=$queryr->fetch_assoc())
    {
    ?>

<?php echo $row['title'];?>
<a href="#" id="readmore">... Read More</a>
<input type="hidden" id="idd" name="idd" value="<?php echo $row['n_id'];?>" >
<?php } ?>
```

Here is my php code that retrieves values from database. I want to alert the id of each row . Below is my script :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

      $("#readmore").click(function(){
         var id=$("#idd").val();
          alert(id);

    });

    });
</script>
```

At present I am only getting the id of first value fetched from database. How it is possible with the rest of the values? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change ID to CLASS and #readmore to .readmore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `class` selector instead of `id`. `id` supposed to be unique. You can not have same `id` for multiple elements. In this case `class` will work perfectly.

```
<a href="#" class="readmore">... Read More</a>
<input type="hidden" class="idd" name="idd" value="<?php echo $row['n_id'];?>" >

$(".readmore").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // Only if you dont want it to reload
    var id=$(this).next('.idd').val();
    alert(id);
});
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/cqrbhbj5/)

Comment: When i changed like this, I got alert for every value but all Id's returned from database remains same.

Comment: And have `$(".readmore").click(function(e){` e.preventDefault()`

Comment: @mplungjan Missed that one. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

ID needs to be unique:

Change to class="readmore" and input's class="idd" and use

```
 $(".readmore").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault()
   var id=$(this).next(".idd").val();
   alert(id);
 });
```

Alternatively do this:

```
<?php echo $row['title'];?>
<a href="#" class="readmore" data-id="<?php echo $row['n_id'];?>">... Read More</a>
<?php } ?>
```

using

```
 $(".readmore").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault()
   var id=$(this).data("id");
   alert(id);
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

Use jquery each function like this

```
$('.readmore').each(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).next('.idd').val();
    alert(id);
}
```